# Ruby on rails one to many association

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

I am very new to rails. I have a one to many association. Table1 with a few fields. One field is title location, another one title ccode. Table2 how ever only has 2 fields, the first field is also location, and the 2nd is also ccode. This table is just to hold my location. In Table1 when I create an object I assign the ccode and I want to get the corresponding location to the ccode from Table2. Table2 has_many Table1 and Table1 belongs_to Table2. Also I want to display the location in my index view in a `<table>` tag. I think my view code is it looks just like the example I had found and I understand html well enough. The problem I am getting is that my Table2 object returns nil.

Here is what my model for Table1 looks like.

```
class Table1 < ActiveRecord::Base
    belongs_to :table_2

    require 'csv'

    def self.import(file)
        CSV.foreach(file.path, headers: true, row_sep: :auto, col_sep: "\t") do |row|
            Table1.create! row.to_hash
        end
    end
end
```

Here is what my model for Table2 looks like.

```
class Table2 < ActiveRecord::Base
    self.table_name = 'table_2'
    self.primary_key = 'ccode'
    has_many :table1
end
```

Here is what Table1Controller looks like

```
class FinancialsController < ApplicationController

    def index
        @financials = Financial.all
    end

    def create
        @financial_loc_ccode = FinancialLocCcode.create(location_code: params[:location_cd], ccode: @financials.ccode)
    end
end
```

I do not have Table2 controller, everything is done in the Table1 controller, I assume it is because when I started this project there was already a table created for Table2.

Like I said before I am very new to rails and still learning the connections between models and controllers, and how to manipulate the data and has well has displaying it in html.

Any help would be much appreciated.

Comment: What's your question, specifically?

Comment: So is your specific problem that the association isn't taking place? You mentioned that Table2 was returning nil. When? When you create table1 objects you're passing them a row...are you also passing them a Table2 id? If not...then the association with a Table2 object is never occurring.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I'll focus on Table2 being nil.

It's nil because you're not creating it.

Go into your terminal and type `rails g controller table2 create`

open that file and inside of the empty `create` method you will create the new Table2 object.

You can do this many ways, but the most important thing to remember when you have associations is that you need to define the association when you're creating it.

I'll give you an example:

Let's say I have a User model

**User Model**

```
class User < ActiveRecord::Base
has_many :posts

end
```

Now let's say I have a Post model and I want the user to be able to create many posts.

**Post Model**

```
class Post < ActiveRecord::Base
belongs_to :user

end
```

Now this is the important part where we will utilize your table2 controller

When I create a new post, it has to `belongs_to` a user, therefor we will do this

**Post Controller**

```
class PostsController < ApplicationController

  def create
    #store the object that has many posts as a variable
    @user = current_user

    #the important part, when you create a post you need to do this
    @post = @user.posts.create(post_params)
  end

end
```

Whats happening here is, Rails is creating the new post UNDER ownership of the `@user`. That is how you establish a relationship by association.

I hope this helped clear up relationships a little bit, if not here are some docs that might help too.

http://guides.rubyonrails.org/association_basics.html